# How to compare one-hot encoded columns for matches?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this:

```
index | 1 | 2 | 3 |  
  A   | 1 | 0 | 1 |  
  B   | 0 | 1 | 1 |  
  C   | 1 | 0 | 0 |  
  D   | 1 | 0 | 0 |  
  E   | 0 | 0 | 1 |
```

My goal is to create three additional columns which values will match the next condition:

```
col1 == duplicate of column 1  
col2 == 1 for all indices that are present (1) in column 2 but we not (0) in col1 + indices tagged 1 from col1  
col3 == 1 for all indices that are present in column 2 but not in col2 + indices from col2
```

as a result, the next df must be obtained:

```
index | col1 | col2 | col3 |  
  A   |    1 | 1    |    1 |  
  B   |    0 | 1    |    1 |  
  C   |    1 | 1    |    1 |  
  D   |    1 | 1    |    1 |  
  E   |    0 | 0    |    1 |
```

My attempt was to use np.where but this line

```
 np.where((dff[2] == dff['col1']) & (dff[2] != dff['col1']), 1, 0)
```

expectedly produces only zeros

Comment: probably you need to use `|` (or) instead `&` (and) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the logic:

```
df["col1"] = df["1"]
df["col2"] = (df["2"] & (~df["1"])) | df["1"]
df["col3"] = (df["2"] & (~df["col2"])) | df["col2"]
```

The result is:

```
  index  1  2  3  col1  col2  col3
0     A  1  0  1     1     1     1
1     B  0  1  1     0     1     1
2     C  1  0  0     1     1     1
3     D  1  0  0     1     1     1
4     E  0  0  1     0     0     0
```